# What is the use case for Moxie?

Tags: moose, perl

[Moxie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moxie) seems to be very Moose-esque but the title is pretty uninformative,

> Moxie - Not Another Moose Clone

Reading it, it seems to use [`B::CompilerPhase::Hook`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::CompilerPhase::Hook) for extra voodoo. What is the end purpose of this library? If it's not a Moose clone, what does it intend to do differently?

The description seems pretty vague too,

> reference implementation for an object system built on top of a set of modules.

Is there a specification for Moxie?

Comment: Isn't that the thing Stevan is always presenting with the _Hold my beer and watch this_ talks? [Fosdem 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BowSFrSph6k) and [TPC 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5U7eoeuO90). From what I can remember, most of the specs seem to be in his head. Damn it, Stevan. :)

Answer (score 3):

Moxie is the Moose-like system that Stevan Little hopes to get included in the Perl core at some point.

This video from last month's TPC explains it all in a lot more detail - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5U7eoeuO90